# Launch WPF from ASP.NET page button click

Tags: asp.net, wpf

I am trying to write an aspx page containing a button whose click event should result in opening of a WPF form for further processing. I am trying to use a new process object to launch the WPF application.

I am using the following code in the code behind:

```
protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process WPF = new Process();
            WPF.StartInfo.FileName = "WpfApplication1.exe";
            WPF.Start();
        }
```

On execution, the button click executes without any exception, but the WPF window is not opened.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I googled a bit and found the following discussion: 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9a30db03-5226-4bfa-bb2a-89b74614003b/                                       

The summary is WPF cannot be launched from ASP.NET. For that XBAP is required.

Comment: your comment is the answer (it's exactly what i would have said in my answer).

Comment: Please do not post that as a comment, post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted starts (or attempts to start) the WPF application **on the server**

If you want the client to run a WPF application you could use an XBAP application or a regular WPF application that is distributed through ClickOnce deployment so you can add a link to the application on your web page.

Answer (score 0):

To launch WPF form from asp.net go to the **View Code** of code behind and Create an object for the WPF form and in the Page_Load event paste the following code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                mainWindow.Show();
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            });
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
            createDB();
        }
```