# using click once deployment in asp.net mvc

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, clickonce

I am trying to build a ASP.NET MVC website wherein I need to use a WPF application. I had posted an earlier question on how to launch WPF on button click

([Launch WPF from ASP.NET page button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762040/launch-wpf-from-asp-net-page-button-click)), but found that WPF cannot be deployed directly in ASP.NET.

On searching a bit more, I found that Click once deployment can be used for this situation, but am not able to figure out the syntax.

I need to deploy WPF exe to the webpage user on the click of a link or button, so that the exe can be opened on the client end.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio publish feature to create the app manifest, deployment manifest, index.html, etc. then just grab the link from the index.html that was generated for you and use that to launch the ClickOnce install.